# Magento cant find reference of js

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I'm on function `_prepareLayout()`

`magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\downloadable\product\edit\downloadable\links.phtml:`

```
 protected function _prepareLayout()
{
        $this->setChild(
        'upload_button',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')->addData(array(
            'id'      => '',
            'label'   => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Upload Files'),
            'type'    => 'button',
            'onclick' => 'Downloadable.massUploadByType(\'links\');Downloadable.massUploadByType(\'linkssample\')'
        ))
    );


}
```

Could you mention what its the source of: `'Downloadable.massUploadByType(\'links\');Downloadable.massUploadByType(\'linkssample\')'`

Comment: Its not really clear what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable.phtml:

```
massUploadByType : function(type){
    try {
        this.uploaderObj.get(type).each(function(item){
            container = item.value.container.up('tr');
            if (container.visible() && !container.hasClassName('no-display')) {
                item.value.upload();
            } else {
                Downloadable.unsetUploaderObj(type, item.key);
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            console.log(e);
        } catch (e2) {
            alert(e.name + '\n' + e.message);
        }
    }
}
```